# Why doesn't my Textbox update with Thread-safe calls using InvokeRequired?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, textbox, invokerequired

UpDate1:

More detail: Thread 1 and 2 must be continuously active.  Thread 1 is updating its GUI and doing HTTP POSTs.  Thread 2 is using HTTPListener for incoming HTTP POSTs, and supplying that data to Thread 1.  So the GUI needs to be display with current Textbox values and updated when Thread 2 supplies the data.  Will Servy's or another approach allow both Threads to do their work concurrently?  It appears the main thread waits for Thread 2 to complete it's work.  It then takes the prepWork and does work with it.  I coded in Servy's example but I couldn't find a definition for Run() with the Task class.  It's library has no such method.  I'm using Net 4.0 on VS 2010.  Is there an equivalent method to use?  Start() didn't compile either and I understand you can only run the Task once.  Thanks for any additional assistance you can share.

Original Question:

I've tested code that will successfully kick off my event and update my GUI textbox in an event handler if the event is kicked off in what I understand as the UI Thread 1.  When I attempt to call a Thread 1 method Fire() from my independent Thread 2 method PrepareDisplay(), Fire() is called and in turns fires off the event.  I put in some Thread-safe call code (modeled from MSDN tutorial on Thread-Safety in WinForms), but the event handler still doesn't update the Textbox.  When stepping thru the code, it appears that the InvokeRequired is false.  My eventual goal is to pass data from Thread 2 to UI Thread 1 and update the Textboxes with the new data.  I don't understand why the Thread-safe code isn't enabling this.  Can someone help me understand this better, and what I have neglected?  Below is the code:

Thank you very much,

```
namespace TstTxtBoxUpdate
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Aag_PrepDisplay aag_Prep1 = new Aag_PrepDisplay();

            Thread AagPrepDisplayThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(aag_Prep1.PrepareDisplay));
            AagPrepDisplayThread.Start();

            while(!AagPrepDisplayThread.IsAlive)
                ;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new SetOperation());
        }
    }
}

namespace TstTxtBoxUpdate
{
    // Thread 1: UI
    public partial class SetOperation : Form
    {
        private string text;
        public event Action<object> OnChDet;

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        private Thread demoThread = null;

        public SetOperation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OnChDet += chDetDisplayHandler;
        }

        public void FireEvent(Aag_PrepDisplay aagPrep)
        {
            OnChDet(mName);
        }

        private void chDetDisplayHandler(object name)
        {
            this.demoThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcSafe));
            this.demoThread.Start();
        }

        private void ThreadProcSafe()
        {
            this.SetText("402.5");
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if(this.actFreqChan1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.actFreqChan1.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace TstTxtBoxUpdate
{
    // Thread 2: Data prepare
    public class Aag_PrepDisplay
    {
        #region Fields

        private Aag_PrepDisplay mAagPrep;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties

        public Aag_PrepDisplay AagPrepDisp;

        public Aag_PrepDisplay AagPrep
        {
            get { return mAagPrep; }
            set { mAagPrep = value; }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Methods

        public void PrepareDisplay()
        {
            mAagPrep = new Aag_PrepDisplay();
            SetOperation setOp1 = new SetOperation();
            setOp1.FireEvent(mAagPrep);     // calls Thread 1 method that will fire the event
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting to the point of calling `InvokeRequired` when your main thread is still on `Thread.Sleep`.  It hasn't even gotten to the point of creating a message loop yet (which is one in `Application.Run`) so there *is no* message loop for `Invoke` to marshal a call to.

There are all sorts of issues here.  You're creating multiple instance of your form, one that you show, and *an entirely different form* that you're setting the text of.  You clearly did not intend to do this; you want to have a single form that you're setting the text for.

Your main thread should not be doing a busywait until your first thread finishes.  It likely shouldn't be there at all.  If it weren't for the fact that your new thread is creating *yet another* new thread, the fact that your main thread is blocking until the second thread finishes and the second thread is trying to marshall a call to the main thread, it would normally deadlock.  You shouldn't really be creating a second new thread here at all, but this is a case of two bugs "cancelling each other out".  It prevents the deadlock, but both are still incorrect, and inhibit your ability to get to a working solution.

You also shouldn't have the `Thread.Sleep` in the main thread at all.  I have no idea what purpose that's trying to achieve.

If you're goal is simply to start some long running work before showing the first form and then to update that form when you have your results, you're doing *way* more work than you need to do.

To do this we can have our form accept a `Task` in its constructor representing the completion of the long running work.  It can add a continuation to that task to set a label, or a textbox, or do...whatever, with the results of that Task.

```
public class SetOperation  : Form
{
    private Label label;
    public SetOperation(Task<string> prepWork)
    {
        prepWork.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            label.Text = t.Result;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

Then the main thread simply needs to start a new `Task` to do the given work in a thread pool thread and pass that in to our form:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Task<string> prepWork = Task.Run(() => DoWork());
    Application.Run(new SetOperation(prepWork));
}

private static string DoWork()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);//placeholder for real work
    return "hi";
}
```

And we're done.  Note that `DoWork` should probably be in its own class designed for handling your business logic; it probably shouldn't be stuck into the `Program` class.

Comment: Servy, thanks for your assistance.  I posted updated information to the above original question with some more questions.  Thanks again for additional recommendations you can share.

Comment: @Kent It's still not sufficently clear what you're *actually* trying to do.  Without knowing, specifically, what needs to happen, there isn't really much more that I can say.

Comment: Sorry Servy.  1) Main() should fire off 2 threads.  2) Thread 2 Aag_PrepDisplay() handles data from incoming client HTTP POSTs.  It takes the posted data and presents it for Main Thread 1 methods.  3) Main Thread 1 will periodically perform HTTP POSTs to a server.  Those POSTs will contain updated data from Thread 2. That data will also be GUI displayed.  4) These are ongoing tasks for both threads.  5) Task.Run(() => DoWork()) did not compile.  The error message said Run has no definition.  Task class doesn't appear to have Run(). 6) Does your approach run both threads concurrently? Thanks

Comment: @Kent You shouldn't be creating any new threads whatsoever to do that.  You should simply be doing the work asynchronously.  If you want to execute some code periodically a `Timer` is an effective way of handling that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm receiving periodic POSTs.  I randomly POST out. Can I synchronously listen, receive, prepare & display incoming data, while I asynchronously POST?  Doesn't the synchronous incoming event block random POSTs?  I want to update Textbox data, but not sure a Timer should drive it. I thought incoming event should. Although it's a periodic event, shouldn't I treat it asynchronously?  Not sure when data starts arriving. I thought it best to handle the incoming and outgoing tasks in separate threads.  Can you explain how a single thread can handle it concurrently & not block the tasks? Thnx

Comment: @Kent You should do *all* of that asynchronously.  You shouldn't be synchronously blocking on any of that IO.  Doing work "periodically" seemed to imply "every X interval of time", which would be a timer.  If there is some other event indicating when you should do...whatever, then that's entirely fine to.